# What is the JAVA equivalent of ResultSet.IsEmpty in the SmartTarget API

Tags: smarttarget

The SmartTarget 2014 API for .NET has a handy `IsEmpty()` method on the `Tridion.SmartTarget.Query.ResultSet` class. You can use this to figure out if the query to SDL Fredhopper did return anything at all. The result set could be empty if there no items, promotions or other things returned by Fredhopper, or if the query timed out.

In the Java verison of API there is no com.tridion.smarttarget.query.ResultSet.isEmpty() or similar. I tried to test if the getItemsTotalCount() is null or 0 (although that is not the same kind of comparison) but that one throws an null pointer exception if the query times out.

So how should I test in the Java API whether I got any results from my query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IsEmpty property in .NET just checks if the number of Promotions is zero (which is not entirely true if there are search results present).

You can do the same check in Java by calling `resultSet.getPromotions().isEmpty()`.

The getPromotions method will never return `null` currently, but checking for that could prevent possible NullPointerExceptions in the future.